# Custom serialization of a dictionary fails when xml has indentation/line break

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, ixmlserializable

In order to have a cleaner XML of a Dictionary serialization, I wrote a custom class, that implements `IXmlSerializable`.

My custom class is defined like this:

```
public class MyCollection : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>, IXmlSerializable
{
    private const string XmlElementName = "MyData";
    private const string XmlAttributeId = "Id";

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if(reader.LocalName == XmlElementName)
            {
                var tag = reader.GetAttribute(XmlAttributeId);
                var content = reader.ReadElementContentAsString(); 

                this.Add(tag, content);
            }
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (string key in this.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(XmlElementName);
            writer.WriteAttributeString(XmlAttributeId, key);
            writer.WriteString(this[key]);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

My code works with this XML snippet:

```
<MyCollection xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MyData Id="1">some content</MyData>
    <MyData Id="2">some other content</MyData>
</MyCollection>
```

However, when I have this minified XML, my code throws an exception:

```
<MyCollection xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><MyData Id="1">some content </MyData><MyData Id="2">some other content</MyData></MyCollection>
```

The exception is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type EndElement
```

It's thrown on the call to `ReadElementContentAsString`.

How to fix my code?

I can repro the issue using :

```
var xml = @"<MyCollection xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""><MyData Id=""1"">some content </MyData><MyData Id=""2"">some other content</MyData></MyCollection>";

var raw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyCollection));

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(raw))
{
    var result = serializer.ReadObject(ms); // Exception throws here
}
```

Comment: What if you change your code to: `if(reader.LocalName == XmlElementName && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)`. You seem to be trying to read element content when you are on the closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that [`reader.ReadElementContentAsString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162529(v=vs.110).aspx) positions the reader at the beginning of the next node, not the end of the current node.  Then, your subsequent unconditional call to [`reader.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) consumes that next node.  When that node is whitespace no harm is done, but when the node is an element, the element is skipped.

The following version of your `MyCollection` fixes this problem:

```
public class MyCollection : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        using (var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            XmlKeyValueListHelper.ReadKeyValueXml(subReader, this);
        }
        // Consume the EndElement also (or move past the current element if reader.IsEmptyElement).
        reader.Read();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlKeyValueListHelper.WriteKeyValueXml(writer, this);
    }
}

public static class XmlKeyValueListHelper
{
    private const string XmlElementName = "MyData";
    private const string XmlAttributeId = "Id";

    public static void WriteKeyValueXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> collection)
    {
        foreach (var pair in collection)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(XmlElementName);
            writer.WriteAttributeString(XmlAttributeId, pair.Key);
            writer.WriteString(pair.Value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }

    public static void ReadKeyValueXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> collection)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            return;
        }

        reader.ReadStartElement(); // Advance to the first sub element of the list element.
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == XmlElementName)
            {
                var tag = reader.GetAttribute(XmlAttributeId);
                string content;
                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    content = string.Empty;
                    // Move past the end of item element
                    reader.Read();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Read content and move past the end of item element
                    content = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
                collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(tag, content));
            }
            else
            {
                // For instance a comment.
                reader.Skip();
            }
        }
        // Move past the end of the list element
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- By using [`XmlReader.ReadSubtree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx) I ensure that `ReadXml()` does not read past the end of the `MyCollection` element thus corrupting future elements -- an easy mistake to make when implementing `IXmlSerializable`.
- By checking for `reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == XmlElementName` I ignore unexpected types of nodes such as comments.

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o1pgqU).

Comment: thanks it works like a charm. Using XmlReader is not obvious :(

Comment: thanks a lot for reading in a subtree. I used that until sub.EOF == true.