# XmlReader behaves different with line breaks

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

If the data is on a single line the 
`index=int.Parse(logDataReader.ReadElementContentAsString());` 
and
`value=double.Parse(logDataReader.ReadElementContentAsString(),`
cause the cursor to move forward. If I take those calls out I see it loop 6 times in debug.

In the following only 3 `<data>` are read (and they are wrong as the value is for the next index) on the first (`<logData id="Bravo">`).  On the second (`<logData id="Bravo">`) all `<data>` are read.

It is not an option to edit the xml and put in line breaks as that file is created dynamically (by XMLwriter). The `NewLineChars` setting is a line feed.  From XMLwriter it is actually just one line - I broke it down to figure out where it was breaking.  In the browser it is displayed properly.

**How to fix this?**

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log>
   <logData id="Alpha">
      <data><index>100</index><value>150</value></data>
      <data><index>110</index><value>750</value></data>
      <data><index>120</index><value>750</value></data>
      <data><index>130</index><value>150</value></data>
      <data><index>140</index><value>0</value></data>
      <data><index>150</index><value>222</value></data>
   </logData>
   <logData id="Bravo">
      <data>
         <index>100</index>
         <value>25</value>
      </data>
      <data>
         <index>110</index>
         <value>11</value>
      </data>
      <data>
         <index>120</index>
         <value>1</value>
      </data>
      <data>
         <index>130</index>
         <value>25</value></data>
      <data>
         <index>140</index>
         <value>0</value>
      </data>
      <data>
         <index>150</index>
         <value>1</value>
      </data>
   </logData>
</log>
```

And my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<LogData> logDatas = GetLogDatasFromFile("singleVersusMultLine.xml");
    Debug.WriteLine("Main");
    Debug.WriteLine("logData");
    foreach (LogData logData in logDatas)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"    logData.ID {logData.ID}");
        foreach(LogPoint logPoint in logData.LogPoints)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"        logData.Index {logPoint.Index}  logData.Value {logPoint.Value}");
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("end");
}       
public static List<LogData> GetLogDatasFromFile(string xmlFile)
{
    List<LogData> logDatas = new List<LogData>();

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile))
    {
        // move to next "logData"
        while (reader.ReadToFollowing("logData"))
        {
            var logData = new LogData(reader.GetAttribute("id"));
            using (var logDataReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                // inside "logData" subtree, move to next "data"
                while (logDataReader.ReadToFollowing("data"))
                {
                    // move to index
                    logDataReader.ReadToFollowing("index");
                    // read index
                    var index = int.Parse(logDataReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                    // move to value
                    logDataReader.ReadToFollowing("value");
                    // read value
                    var value = double.Parse(logDataReader.ReadElementContentAsString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    logData.LogPoints.Add(new LogPoint(index, value));
                }
            }
            logDatas.Add(logData);
        }
    }
    return logDatas;
}

public class LogData
{
    public string ID { get; }
    public List<LogPoint> LogPoints { get; } = new List<LogPoint>();
    public LogData (string id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
}
public class LogPoint
{
    public int Index { get; }
    public double Value { get; }
    public LogPoint ( int index, double value)
    {
        Index = index;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The whitespace gets read as an extra node, of type [`XmlNodeType.Whitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype.aspx).  If you have code that makes one too many calls to `XmlReader.Read()`, then if the XML is indented the whitespace node gets skipped, but if the XML is not indented then something important gets skipped.  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282052/3744182) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165632/3744182) for examples of such.

Comment: @dbc Thanks.  Please post as an answer.  Unless someone post a solution in the next couple days I will accept.  What is interesting is LINQ XML does not have this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is as follows.  According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162529.aspx#Anchor_2) for `XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString()`:

> This method reads the start tag, the contents of the element, and moves the reader **past** the end element tag.

And from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162536.aspx#Anchor_2) for `XmlReader.ReadToFollowing(String)`:

> It advances the reader to the **next** following element that matches the specified name and returns true if a matching element is found.

Thus, after the call to `ReadElementContentAsString()`, since the reader has been advanced to the next node, it might already be positioned on the next `<value>` or `<data>` node.  Then when you call `ReadToFollowing()` this element node is **skipped** because the method unconditionally moves on to the **next** node with the correct name.  But if the XML is indented then the next node immediately after the call to `ReadElementContentAsString()` will be an `XmlNodeType.Whitespace` node, protecting against this bug.

The solution is to check whether the reader is already positioned correctly after the call to `ReadElementContentAsString()`.  First, introduce the following extension method:

```
public static class XmlReaderExtensions
{
    public static bool ReadToFollowingOrCurrent(this XmlReader reader, string localName, string namespaceURI)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == localName && reader.NamespaceURI == namespaceURI)
            return true;
        return reader.ReadToFollowing(localName, namespaceURI);
    }
}
```

Then modify your code as follows:

```
public static List<LogData> GetLogDatasFromFile(string xmlFile)
{
    List<LogData> logDatas = new List<LogData>();

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile))
    {
        // move to next "logData"
        while (reader.ReadToFollowing("logData", ""))
        {
            var logData = new LogData(reader.GetAttribute("id"));
            using (var logDataReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                // inside "logData" subtree, move to next "data"
                while (logDataReader.ReadToFollowing("data", ""))
                {
                    // move to index
                    logDataReader.ReadToFollowing("index", "");
                    // read index
                    var index = XmlConvert.ToInt32(logDataReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                    // move to value
                    logDataReader.ReadToFollowingOrCurrent("value", "");
                    // read value
                    var value = XmlConvert.ToDouble(logDataReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                    logData.LogPoints.Add(new LogPoint(index, value));
                }
            }
            logDatas.Add(logData);
        }
    }
    return logDatas;
}
```

Notes:

- Always prefer to use `XmlReader` methods in which the local name and namespace are specified separately, such as [`XmlReader.ReadToFollowing (String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162537.aspx).  When you use a method such as [`XmlReader.ReadToFollowing(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162536.aspx) which accepts a single qualified name, you are implicitly hardcoding the choice of XML *prefix*, which is generally not a good idea.  XML parsing should be independent of prefix choice.
- While you correctly parsed your double using the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` locale, it's even easier to use the methods from the [`XmlConvert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx) class to handle parsing and formatting correctly.
- [`XmlReader.ReadSubtree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx) leaves the `XmlReader` positioned **on** the `EndElement` node of the element being read, so you shouldn't need to call `ReadToFollowingOrCurrent()` afterwards.  (Nice use of `ReadSubtree()` to avoid reading too little or too much by the way; by using this method one can avoid several frequent mistakes with `XmlReader`.)
- As you have found, code that manually reads XML using `XmlReader` should always be unit-tested with both formatted and unformatted XML, because certain bugs will only arise with one or the other.  (See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282052/3744182), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165632/3744182) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845282/3744182) for other examples of such.)

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/feM6GV).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed that code (which I provided to you in your another question) is wrong. `ReadToFollowing` will read to the next element with this name even if it's cursor is already positioned on element with this name. When there is a whitespace - after you read `index`, cursor moves to that whitespace and `ReadToFollowing("value")` works as you expect. However, if there is no whitespace, cursor is already on `value` node and so `ReadToFollowing("value")` reads to the next "value" in subsequent "data" node.

I think the following would be a safer approach:

```
public static List<LogData> GetLogDatasFromFile(string xmlFile) {
    List<LogData> logDatas = new List<LogData>();

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile)) {
        LogData currentData = null;
        while (reader.Read()) {
            if (reader.IsStartElement("logData")) {
                // we are positioned on start of logData
                if (currentData != null)
                    logDatas.Add(currentData);
                currentData = new LogData(reader.GetAttribute("id"));
            }
            else if (reader.IsStartElement("data")) {
                // we are on start of "data"
                // we always have "currentData" at this point                        
                Debug.Assert(currentData != null);
                reader.ReadToFollowing("index");
                var index = int.Parse(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                // check if we are not already on "value"
                if (!reader.IsStartElement("value"))
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("value");
                var value = double.Parse(reader.ReadElementContentAsString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                currentData.LogPoints.Add(new LogPoint(index, value));
            }
        }

        if (currentData != null)
            logDatas.Add(currentData);
    }

    return logDatas;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will test tomorrow.  It so confused me when you prior code broke when I copied into the real project.

Comment: @paparazzo well I try to test code before posting answers, but this time I made an uncaught mistake, happens.

Comment: Your code worked with the data I posted.  I broke out the line breaks for a cleaner presentation in the question.

Comment: @paparazzo yes I tested on your data of course, that gave me false feeling my code is correct :) By the way, I would consider using xml serializer, because as you see, `XmlReader` is not very user friendly. Unless your xml files are big and you are forced to reading them in streamed manner.

Comment: This is just a coding test for a job.  I just need it to work.   Not production code.

Comment: Nice answer.  It works.  The other was posted first.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix but to me not an acceptable answer. XMLreader should not behave differently with line breaks.

In `XmlWriter` this will put line breaks in the text:

```
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fileNameXML, xmlWriterSettings))
{
```

I found this [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/112666/C-XML-Writer-Settings-Adding-Line-breaks-indentati).